# better way of doing dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
UG=[
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","user_name":"tom"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup2","user_name":"wilson"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","user_name":"kevin"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup2","user_name":"donna"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup3","user_name":"john"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","user_name":"steve"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup2","user_name":"jose"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup3","user_name":"jags"}]
PG=[
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","device_name":"device1"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","device_name":"device2"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup2","device_name":"device1"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","device_name":"device2"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup1","device_name":"device3"},
    {"group_member":"myGroup3","device_name":"device1"}]
DG=[
    {"device_name":"device1","server":"server1"},
    {"device_name":"device2","server":"server2"},
    {"device_name":"device3","server":"server3"},
    {"device_name":"device4","server":"server4"},
    {"device_name":"device5","server":"server5"},
    {"device_name":"device6","server":"server6"}
    ]
```

I need to compare the lists and prepare a list of dictionary with the following condition

```
UG[i]['group_member'] == PG[j]['group_member'] && PG[j]['device_name'] == UG[k]['device_name']
```

here is my implementation

```
# output array
output=[]
for i in DG:
    for j in PG:
        if i["device_name"] == j["device_name"]:
            for k in UG:
                if k["group_member"] == j["group_member"]:
                   output.append({"user_name":k["user_name"],"group_member":k["group_member"],"device_name":j["device_name"],"server":i["server"]})

for m in output:
  print m
```

desired output============

```
[
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'tom', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'}, 
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'kevin', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'steve', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'wilson', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'}
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'donna', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'},
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'jose', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'}, 
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'john', 'group_member': 'myGroup3', 'device_name': 'device1'}, 
    {'server': 'server1', 'user_name': 'jags', 'group_member': 'myGroup3', 'device_name': 'device1'}, 
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'tom', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}, 
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'kevin', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'steve', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'tom', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}, 
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'kevin', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'server': 'server2', 'user_name': 'steve', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'},
    {'server': 'server3', 'user_name':'tom', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'}, 
    {'server': 'server3', 'user_name': 'kevin', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'},
    {'server': 'server3', 'user_name': 'steve', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'}
]
```

how can i improve my implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using a list comprehension. But first let's create a functional dict update function, since `dict`'s update method doesn't return a new dict (but, rather, updates the current one):

```
def updt(d1, d2):
    d3 = d1.copy()
    d3.update(d2)
    return d3
```

Now let's get wild with the list comprehension:

```
dictlist = [updt(updt(ug, pg), dg) for ug in UG for pg in PG for dg in DG if ug['group_member'] == pg['group_member'] and pg['device_name'] == dg['device_name']]
```

Here is the result:

```
for d in dictlist:
    print(d)
```

And you have:

```
{'user_name': 'tom', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'tom', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'tom', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'tom', 'server': 'server3', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'}
{'user_name': 'wilson', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'kevin', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'kevin', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'kevin', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'kevin', 'server': 'server3', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'}
{'user_name': 'donna', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'john', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup3', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'steve', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'steve', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'steve', 'server': 'server2', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device2'}
{'user_name': 'steve', 'server': 'server3', 'group_member': 'myGroup1', 'device_name': 'device3'}
{'user_name': 'jose', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup2', 'device_name': 'device1'}
{'user_name': 'jags', 'server': 'server1', 'group_member': 'myGroup3', 'device_name': 'device1'}
```

which seems to be what you want, although in a different order.

Comment: I'd suggest using `itertools.product` to improve readability further: `[... for ug, pg, dg in product(UG, PG, DG) if ...]`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, like the idea, tried it, but it remains the same expression length. Compare: `for ug in UG for pg in PG for dg in DG` to `for ug, pg, dg in product(UG, PG, DG)`. And I even like to use the module name, so it becomes `itertools.product`...

Comment: Personally I just find it easier to reason about a single cartesian product call instead of repeated for ... for ... for ... constructs. YMMV :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have thousands of records here is generator

```
from itertools import product

def produce():
    for dg, pg, ug in product(DG, PG, UG):
        if pg['device_name'] == dg['device_name'] and ug['group_member'] == pg['group_member']:
            item = dg.copy()
            item.update(pg)
            item.update(ug)
            yield item
```